# Discrete math [Counting]

Tags: combinatorics

How many passwords of exactly $8$ upper case letters contain:(a)  the letter $X$?
(b)  the letters $X$ and $Y$?

For the first one  the answer I have written is $26^7$ as one spot is occupied by $X$ but I am still not sure of it. 
Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hint: Does order matter in passwords?  Have you accounted for the position of $X$?

Comment: No the order does not matter

Comment: @m.saza of course order matters

Comment: Seriously?  Order doesn't matter???  Well, a text can set up a question any way it sees fit but I can't imagine any text defining something called a "word" if order didn't matter.  After all INTEGRAL and TRIANGLE are different words and ther is no RELATING between them.  (And there's no altering that fact; I'm just alerting you.)

Comment: If order matters, you have undercounted.  If order does not matter, then you have overcounted.

Comment: If order doesn't matter in passwords, then I should be able to log on to my computer account using the letters and numbers of my password in some strange order. It doesn't seem to work that way.

Comment: Alright my bad, Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are altogether $26^8$ passwords of $8$ letters. Of these, $25^8$ contain no X. So $26^8-25^8$ do contain X. (You might find it instructive to check that this agrees with the sum obtained by Paul Childs in his answer.)

To count the passwords that contain both X and Y, start with all $26^8$ passwords as above; subtract off $25^8$ that don't contain X and another $25^8$ that don't contain Y; realize that words that contain neither X nor Y have been subtracted off twice; so add those $24^8$ words back on. So you get $26^8-(2\times 25^8)+24^8$.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to approach this problem. You can do it directly, as Paul did in his answer. You can look at the complement of each set (i.e. passwords that don't contain the letter $X$ and those that don't contain $X$ and $Y$). You can use inclusion-exclusion (look at how many strings contain at least $k$ of the letter $X$ and sieve to get the number containing exactly $k$).

The problem with $26^7$ as an answer is that it doesn't account for where the $X$ is in the string. Note that we have $8$ different sets of size $26^7$:

- Strings of the form $X*******$
- Strings of the form $*X******$
- Strings of the form $**X*****$
- etc.

But there are overlaps. For example, the string $XABCXDEF$ is in both the first and fourth set.

You can account for this using inclusion-exclusion or you can be careful making sure that your second set doesn't overlap the first and the third doesn't overlap the first two, etc.

However, take note that these methods of counting become more complicated when you're looking at both $X$ and $Y$. The second method I mentioned (looking at complements) makes both problems easy. But you should keep all methods in mind to build up a good toolbox for solving counting problems.

Answer (score 0):

For a

With X in position 1 there are 26^7 possibilities.

With X in position 2 and not X in position 1 there are 25 * 26^6 possibilities.

Sum = 26^7 + 25*26^6 + 25^2 * 26^5 + ... + 25^7